# Piping personal access token into az devops login for Windows cmd

Tags: python, azure, cmd, azure-devops, azure-cli

What specific syntax needs to be changed in the Python script below to enable the personal access token to be sucessfully read into the `az devops login` command without throwing an error?

**CURRENT ERROR:**

The error being thrown currently is:

```
'actual-personal-access-token-goes-here' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

**CALLING PROGRAM:**

The Python program that is being called from windows CMD when the error is thrown is called `myScript.py` and includes:

```
import subprocess
import re
ansi_escape = re.compile(r'\x1B\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]')
azPat = 'actual-personal-access-token-goes-here'
orgServiceURL = 'actual-org-service-url-goes-here'
azdoLoginCmd='az devops login --organization '+orgServiceURL 
dblCmd = azPat + " | " + azdoLoginCmd

proc = subprocess.Popen( dblCmd,cwd=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
while True:
  line = proc.stdout.readline()
  if line:
    thetext=line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n')
    decodedline=ansi_escape.sub('', thetext)
    print(decodedline)
  else:
    break
```

**CALL TO INVOKE PROGRAM:**

The command typed into windows CMD that calls the above program and throws the above error is:

```
python3 myScript.py
```

**OFFICIAL DOCUMENTATION:**

The official Microsoft documentation is [at this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows) .

Answer (score 0):

The following is what works to resolve the error in the OP:

```
azdoLoginCmd= "ECHO " + azPat + " | " + "az devops login --organization "+organization
```

We tested this to validate it.